# I am trying pass the obj to the frontend but it is not working passing it show the previous values not the updated values in django

Tags: javascript, django, jinja2, fetch-api

when I am trying to pass the context in the post method it works and displays the content in the front-end but when I am trying to pass the context in the get method it is not working. I am trying to change the view based on the filer.

my view

```
def testing_view(request):
 context={'test':43}
 if request.GET:
     flag=request.GET.get('flag')
     value=request.GET.get('testing_value')
     print('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&','get initialized')
     if flag:
         context['obj']=value
         context['test']=1
         print('&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&','obj',context)
         return render(request, 'testing.html', context)
     print('&&&&&&&&&&&','exit1')
     return render(request, 'testing.html', context)

 print('&&&&&&&&&&&','exit2')
 return render(request, 'testing.html', context)
```

my js

```
function display_value(src)
{
    testing_value=src.value
    console.log("hi it working",testing_value)
    url='/test?testing_value='+testing_value+'&flag='+1
    fetch(url,{ 
       method: 'GET',//get 
    }
   )

}
```

my template

```
<body>
    <div >
    <p>Please select your age:</p>
    <input type="radio" id="age1" name="age" value="4" onchange="display_value(this)">
    <label for="age1">4</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="age2" name="age" value="5" onchange="display_value(this)">
    <label for="age2">5</label><br>
    </div>
    <div>
        
        {{ test }}
        {{ obj  }}
        
    </div>
```

my output

```
06/Jun/2022 17:49:25] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 2508
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& get initialized
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& obj {'test': 1, 'obj': '4'}
[06/Jun/2022 17:49:27] "GET /test/?testing_value=4&flag=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 682
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& get initialized
&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&& obj {'test': 1, 'obj': '5'}
[06/Jun/2022 17:49:31] "GET /test/?testing_value=5&flag=1 HTTP/1.1" 200 682
```

the obj and test variable in context is not updating

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/effS7.png)

Comment: How does the template look like? Could you share a sample of the context variable at the GET case?

Comment: I have added the template over in the post

Comment: Could you also share a sample output of `content` variable in the GET case? You have to prove first that it is the same as in the POST case. The definition of `chapter_list()` function may be relevant as well.

Comment: I have added everything in this post

Comment: Wait, now it's a different problem. Do you want to update the page via JS?

Comment: Yeah that's what I am trying to do from starting....i want to change view based on the select options...i am new to django...i do not know what to do

Answer (score 0):

Is flag actually pulling anything from the request?

Do you have chapter_flag_list = [] somewhere?

My guess is that flag = '' from the request, then your if statement isn't being triggered and your list is staying empty.